# Replacing last 4 bytes in Long number with different 4 bytes number

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

This is what is come up with

```
long longTime64Bits = 1509412598194L;
int  intTime32Bits = 63673;

longTime64Bits &= ~0xFFFFFFFF; // this should set last 32 bits to zero

long new64bitTime = longTime64Bits |= intTime32Bits; // new number with replaced 32 bits
```

I am not sure what is wrong but somehow longTime64Bits (line 3) new value is always coming as zero.

Comment: Where do you assign value to `intTime32Bits`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this produces incorrect result is that `0xFFFFFFFF` an `int` constant. Therefore, `~0xFFFFFFFF` is also an `int`, and it is equal to zero.

Changing the constant to `0xFFFFFFFF00000000L` or using `~0xFFFFFFFFL` will fix the problem.

Comment: `~0xFFFFFFFFL` works too, or even `0xFFFFFFFFL << 32`

Comment: @Bohemian Right, I tested this, and ninja-edited the answer.

Comment: How about `1L << 63 >> 31`? It's arguably more readable too :)

Comment: @Bohemian It's definitely more readable, but it requires a reader who understand sign extension. On the other hand, readers who don't understand sign extension have no business reading code with bit manipulation, so I guess that's fair.